# Move this array "sort" operation to a separate statement

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a code like this and I am getting (Move this array "sort" operation to a separate statement) at the very start

```
pkgList
.sort(this.compare)
.map((item) => item.name)
```

but when i refactor to

```
const sortedPkgList = pkgList.sort(this.compare);

sortedPkgList
.map((item) => item.name)
```

I am still getting the same (Move this array "sort" operation to a separate statement). I am not sure what this error means and how to usually solve this kind of problem?
THanks!

Comment: Just `pkgList.sort(this.compare); const names = pkgList.map(item => item.name)`.

Comment: to explain the above comment, sorts the array in place (and returns it) - not sure why you're "getting" that message - or what is producing it

Comment: @Bravo The message is from a linter, subscribing to the philosophy (explicitly followed by e.g. Python) that `pkgList.sort(this.compare).map...` might let a reader think that `sort` is non-destructive, and should not be allowed.

Comment: @Amadan - yes, a linter would explain it - not that the OP stated that they use a linter - which is why I added *what is producing it* to the comment, to nudge the OP into writing questions with **all** relevant information